# While traversing through a directory if a subdirectory is identified how to create an empty file within it.?

Tags: java, file

Code: - lists all the files checks if the file is a subdirectory or not and prints it .
Within the if clause i must embed a code using createNewFile() so that a new file is created in all the subdirectories. How do i do it?

```
File directory = new File(directoryName);                          
    //get all the files from a directory            
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();               
    for (File file : fList){                    
        if (file.isFile()){                         
            System.out.println("Files: " + file.getName());                     
        } else if (file.isDirectory()){     
            file.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("Subdirectory :" +file.getName());   

        }               
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give a new name to the new file you want to create:

```
else if (file.isDirectory()){
            File nf = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"newFile")     
            nf.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("Subdirectory :" +file.getName());   

        }
```

Something like this.

Comment: `File nf = File(file.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"newFile")` should be `File nf = File(file.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"newFile")`

Answer (score 2):

What your code is says is: "If the current file I'm iterating is a directory, then create a new file from this directory". So the `file` your iterating is the `file` you're trying to create, which I'm surprised if works. Instead, create a `new File` with this directory as the parent.

Something like:

```
new File(file, "somefilename");
```

Comment: NilsH: ya thats why it didnt work!! thanks for the explanantion!!